# Authenticate Google with Username and Password

Tags: google-api, google-api-js-client

Is there any API or any way to authenticate google account in just one go.
I don't want the authentication popup to be opened by google which asks user to enter email and Password.

I already have the username and password with me and don't want user to enter again.

Any advice will be very helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps) is no longer supported.

> **Important:** ClientLogin has been [officially deprecated](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html) since April 20, 2012 and is now no longer available. Requests to ClientLogin will fail with a HTTP 404 response. We encourage you to migrate to [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) as soon as possible.

Comment: Many thanks @abraham for your answer. I see that Service account of OAuth is looking promising. Can you please share some link where I can get any sample application by which I get start trying.

Comment: Search for "google client library php" (or whatever language you are using) and you will find documentation and sample projects for that language.

Comment: I found some. Tried too. It opens browser to login and grant permission. That is what I don't want. Getting my point?